# timer script for auto opening link and closing tab? Even possible?

Tags: browser, timer, google-sheets

I have a couple of ads running on spareroom.com. There is a link on each ad to 'renew'. e.g. (i've put 0000001 ad the ad ID in this example):
http://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/advert_renew.pl?advert_id=0000001&flatshare_type=offered

I was wondering if there was a way that if i have this link compiled in a google spreadsheet cell, it could open automatically in a browser window every 20 minutes? This will allow the ad to be renewed regularly. Ideally the window will close by itself - but that sounds quite complex!

Is this sort of thing possible? It would be great if i didn't have to keep going on the website just to press 'renew' constantly.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could show what you have tried so far....!!!!

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for the comment. And apologies its a bit out of my knowledge depth at the moment. I have looked on google for something similar that i could manipulate but i'm not getting any that is similar to what i need - hence, i'm not sure if its even possible! Any help would be ace. Thanks